# add watermark in CI

Tags: php, codeigniter, gdlib

I want to add watermark on new uploded images. I am using CI.

```
public function watermark(){
        $this->load->library('image_lib');
        $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/gallery/d7315a9a3039541431ab8a41820b6f00.jpg';
        $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2015';
        $config['wm_type']          = 'text';
        $config['wm_font_size']     = 16;
        $config['wm_font_color']    = 'ffffff';
        $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
        $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
        $config['wm_padding']       = '20';
        $this->image_lib->initialize($config);
        if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
            echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
        }else{
            echo "Image created";
        }
    }
```

it's not displaying any error but image is not created.

Comment: What does $this->image_lib->watermark(); output?

Comment: is your path correct or try this  ./uploads/gallery/d7315a9a3039541431ab8a41820b6f00.jpg

Answer (score 0):

From the [documentation](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/libraries/image_lib.html):

> Note: In order for the image class to be allowed to do any processing,
>   the image file must have "write" file permissions.

For example, 777.

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
public function image_watermark()//change the class name
{
    $this->load->library('image_lib');

    $config['source_image'] = 'uploads/gallery/d7315a9a3039541431ab8a41820b6f00.jpg';
    $config['wm_text'] = 'Copyright 2015';
    $config['wm_type']          = 'text';
    $config['wm_font_size']     = 16;
    $config['wm_font_color']    = 'ffffff';
    $config['wm_vrt_alignment'] = 'middle';
    $config['wm_hor_alignment'] = 'right';
    $config['wm_padding']       = '5';//less padding

    $this->image_lib->initialize($config);

    if (!$this->image_lib->watermark()) {
        echo $this->image_lib->display_errors();
    }else{
        echo "Image created";
    }
}
```